# How to remove title bar in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, titlebar

I'm using the following code for practising,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BorderLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BorderLayoutDemo.java

I also add

```
frame.setSize(frame.getMaximumSize());
```

in createAndShowGUI() method,

What is more I want this window not to have the title bar, close and minimize buttons.

I tried the following code,

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

If I added this code before the pack(), it goes into infine loop with this exception **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException**

If I added the last line of createAndShowGUI() method it throws **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is displayable.**

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The title bar can be removed by calling [`setUndecorated(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)) on the `Frame` or `JFrame` instance, i.e. by setting the "undecorated" property to `true`. This removes both the title bar **and** the surrounding frame.

Here's the required code for the question:

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // Already there
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setUndecorated(true); // <-- the title bar is removed here
```

---

**On a packed `JFrame`**

`setUndecorated(true)` must be called before `pack()` is being called, either directly or indirectly, for instance through `setVisible(true)`.

Apparently it is not possible to remove the title bar after the packing is performed, this is the documentation of [`Frame#setDecorated(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated(boolean)):

> A frame may have its native decorations (i.e. Frame and Titlebar) turned off with `setUndecorated`. This can only be done while the frame is not displayable. The method will throw a runtime exception: `IllegalComponentStateException` if the frame is displayable.

However, [you can call `Window#dispose()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/875317/589259) on the `Frame` or `JFrame` and then pack it again, which causes the layout of the components within the `JFrame` to be refreshed.

Comment: This only works if you want your frame to be maximized.  If you don't then be sure to setUndecorated(true) before you pack the frame.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the following code snippet in `createAndShowGUI()` worked for me:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("BorderLayoutDemo");
frame.setUndecorated(true); // Remove title bar
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Note that I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve by manually setting the size of an unrealized frame to it's maximum size, which will be `(0, 0)` initially.

Comment: yes thats right, thanks ! after I delete the setSize, it worked. But I couldnt figure out how should I set the size of the JFrame instance to (0, 0) ?