# Java swing disabling the window

Tags: java, swing

I would like to disable the window in my swing application here is a picture to demonstrate what I mean:
[image]

My paint skills are bad but I hope you understand me, the result should look like this:
[image]

The borders are not the issue since it's easy to edit them.

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701716/how-to-remove-title-bar-in-jframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try `frame.setundecorated(true);`

Comment: I clicked plus, thanks it's working but why now I can't move the frame?

Comment: I will when it possible, I have to wait more 6 minutes -.-

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the frame as undecorated:

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```