# Hide windows taskbar and the area where close/minimize button are

Tags: java, swing

I have created a simple java game using swing. It's working fine but the game doesn't go full screen when launched.

I would like the JFrame to cover the whole screen.

How do I hide the taskbar and the area where close/resize buttons are provided?

I have provided the option to close the game within the options in the game. So that external close button would just ruin the looks and the feel. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you can use `setUndecorated(true);` to hide close resize button area

Comment: @FastSnail Can you give some more details about it?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Createundecoratedframe.htm

Comment: @FastSnail Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701716/how-to-remove-title-bar-in-jframe

Comment: @FastSnail I read that. That was helpful too. I will need someone to post an answer to accept and close the question.

Comment: since this is a duplicate question you can close it .no more answers required