# How Can I customise the TitleBar of JDialog , JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, paint, titlebar

Is there any way I can remove the white title bar and change it to black?I am working on making my own look and feel, how can we change the color of it so that all the derivatives that have the title bar should have a black title bar instead of white.

[image]

Comment: Did you search for a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove title bar in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701716/how-to-remove-title-bar-in-jframe)

Comment: @EugenCovaci Yes, I searched for solution. I can remove the titlebar by setting setundecorated(true); but I dont know how turn it black?

Comment: If there is no other way, remove it and add the (x) button and the header text, in the code. that is static anyway :)

Comment: @NenadVichentikj Thank you so much! How can i add the button and header text.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyJDialog extends JDialog{

  public MyJDialog(){
     super()
     // add the text and button here including positioning
  }

}
```