# Is there a way to remove frame decoration without re-opening it?

Tags: java, jframe

I am making a simple bible reader, and I want to have a fullscreen option. By default, the frame is maximized, but the frame is there. I have a method, `setFullScreen`, that removes decoration. However, it does not seem to update after being initialized. Is there a way around this?

`setFullScreen` method:

```
public void setFullScreen() {
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
}
```

Part of the `main` method

```
UI book = new UI();
book.setLabelText(1);
book.setFullScreen();
```

At the same time, `setLabelText` will behave similarly; once I set it the first time, I can't change it.

Comment: No, a frame must not be realised (displayable on the screen/connected to a native peer) in order to remove the decoration.

Comment: How would I work around this?

Comment: Make two frames, one decorated, one undecorated.  Only one of them should be visible at any given time.  If your entire user interface is in a single panel, you can move it from one frame to another simply by adding that panel to the desired frame, since that will automatically remove it from any previous parent.

Comment: Yes it's a duplicate. The accepted answer of that other question is wrong. I don't know the "official procedure" in that case, so I simply posted my answer here despite the duplicate.

Comment: @ChristianHujer I would put a comment under the 'wrong' answer linking to yours here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method `setUndecorated()` can only be used if the frame is not *displayable*. What you could do is make your frame not *displayable* by calling `dispose()`.

Your method `setFullScreen()` could look like this:

```
public void setFullScreen() {
    mainFrame.dispose();
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Depending on your frame contents, you might want to deal with `pack()` and / or `setSize()` explicitly to get best results.

By the way, if you want it to be fullscreen / undecorated always, you could simply ensure that you call `mainFrame.setUndecorated(true)` before you make the frame displayable. The frame is made displayable by methods such as `show()`, `pack()` and `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: Works, but the transition shows the closing animation of the window, and then displays the fullscreen.

Comment: That's unavoidable. It will not get better than that, that's how the classes `Window` and `Frame` (`JFrame` is just derived from them) work. I don't know of any pure Java application which you can put in fullscreen mode which does not "flash" when enabling or disabling fullscreen.