# How to change the color of the title bar in javax.swing?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe, titlebar

I generally use visual studio code or IntelliJ for coding.

In that, I see that the title bar is coloured. Not only in that but in many apps I have seen that. Now I wish to try it out for my own applications also. But I haven't found anything that can accomplish my work.

I generally want like this.

```
jframe.setTitleBarColor(...)
```

But the above type is not available.
Is there any other technique that I can use to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried to change the UIManager properties? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html

Comment: The color of the title bar is determined by the OS.

Comment: So is there no way to do that? But intellij has black(in darkula), vscode has black and MS teams has blue color. So why cant I keep that for my apps also..

Comment: I don't know what language Intellij is written in. Maybe Intellij uses OS system calls to control the background. The Java/Swing API does not give us access to the background of the titlebar.

Comment: Thank you everyone for spending your time on me. And for your suggestions ☺️☺️

Comment: @Ruthvik may be there is a start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/876954/4693472 but it means to draw it yourself

Comment: See [`setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated) to have the title bar painted according to the PLAF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not possible. Because the top-level `JFrame` acquires the look & feel of the machine's operating system.

By the way this program will help you to change the frame appearance with the help of LAF (Look And Feel):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRootPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.DefaultMetalTheme;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel;

public class Main {
  public static void main(final String args[]) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(300, 300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.white);
    f.setContentPane(panel);

    MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new MyDefaultMetalTheme());
    try {
      UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new MetalLookAndFeel());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(f);

    f.setVisible(true);
  }
}

class MyDefaultMetalTheme extends DefaultMetalTheme {
  public ColorUIResource getWindowTitleInactiveBackground() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getWindowTitleBackground() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getPrimaryControlHighlight() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getPrimaryControlDarkShadow() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getPrimaryControl() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getControlHighlight() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getControlDarkShadow() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }

  public ColorUIResource getControl() {
    return new ColorUIResource(java.awt.Color.orange);
  }
}
```